# How to write items in the same array on the row and for the next array skip a line and write the items on the next row in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

`I currently have a list of names in one CSV that are separated ["last name", "first name"]. If there is no name, the array just has ["1"]. Each name on the current CSV is in its own separate array. I'm trying write the names in a CSV so that one column is all last names (and "1's") and the other column is all first names.

My Current CSV looks like

```
Names:
Wayne, Bruce
1
1
1
Parker, Peter 
Kent, Clark
```

I want my CSV to Output

```
Last Name:    First Name:
Wayne         Bruce
1
1
Parker        Peter
Kent          Clark
```

With my current code, anything following a ["1"] is going on a newline, but anything following an array ["last name", "first name"] isn't. Is there any way to fix this in my current code?

```
import re
import csv


trite = open('Lastfirststrip.csv', "r")
spamreader = csv.reader(trite)
twrite = open('LastFirst.csv', 'w')
spamwriter = csv.writer(twrite, delimiter=" ", lineterminator="\n",  skipinitialspace=True)
altwriter = csv.writer(twrite, delimiter=' ', lineterminator=',', skipinitialspace=True )

for column in spamreader:
    c = ","
    d = ",".join(column)
    e = re.findall('[A-Za-z]+',d)

    if len (e) == 1:
        for item in e:
            spamwriter.writerow([item])
    else:
        for item in e:
            altwriter.writerow([item])
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the data, how it looks, and the desired outcome? I'm a little lost by the description.

Comment: ...I'm not convinced your input format is CSV.

Answer (score 0):

This question has the feel of "I have a hammer, so everything looks like a nail."

You're trying to use the csv module to do something that isn't exactly csv.

```
with open("/tmp/input") as fdin, open("/tmp/o", "w") as fdout:                  
    for line in fdin:                                                           
        line = line.strip()                                                     
        if line == "1":                                                         
            print >> fdout, line                                                
            continue                                                            
        if line == "Names:":                                                    
            print >> fdout, "Last Name:\tFirst Name:"                           
            continue                                                            
        first, last = line.split(",")                                           
        print >> fdout, first.strip() + "\t" + last.strip()
```